# Appium - multiple android devices in parallel

Tags: android, testng, appium

I have the appium set up in my windows machine , I am able to run the test in physical android device. I just wanted to know can I run the same tests in multiple devices in parallel.if possible what additional configuration to be done.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: yes, we can spin up multiple instances of appuim  sessions in order to achieve this

Comment: can you share the code please

Comment: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js" -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --no-reset --app D:/dc_MyProductivity_debug.apk --app-pkg com.openstream.cueme.services.workbench --app-wait-package com.openstream.cueme.services.workbench --app-activity com.openstream.mmi.gui.CuemeActivityDelegate --app-wait-activity com.openstream.mmi.gui.CuemeActivityDelegate --platform-name Android --automation-name Appium --platform-version 4.4

Comment: you can have diff session with port changes

Comment: I tried. Tests in emulator runs good. but nothing happens in device connected thru USB. "FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass capabilities
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: make sure you define the capabilities correct

Comment: Yes  did. But no idea where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium grid configuration for multiple devices execution
http://qaautomationworld.blogspot.in/2014/11/appium-remote-execution-grid-execution.html
http://blog.zymr.com/configuring-appium-node-servers-with-selenium-grid